# How to calculate a processor's CPI after a percentage increase?

Tags: cpu, processor

i know how to calculate the overall average CPI of instruction types once given the frequency(F) and the clock cycles(CPI) for each instruction. However i'm having trouble finding out how to find the new CPI when an instruction is optimized/improved.

For example, let's say originally a processor had ALU F of 40% and a CPI of 2, Load had a F of 20% and a CPI of 10, Store had a F of 15% and a CPI of 4 and Branches had a F of 25% and a CPI of 3.

In this case the overall average CPI would be 4.15. However let's say ALU is improved and 80% takes 1 cycle and the other 20% still takes 2 cycles.

How is the new CPI after enhancement is calculated?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing specific about CPUs here.
It's just an algebra question.

The ALU instructions are 40% of the total, so the 80% of the ALU instructions are 0.4 * 0.8 = 32% of the total.
The 20% of 40% is, of course, 8% of the total.

Now it's like having:

- ALU A instructions with frequency 32% and CPI 1.
- ALU B instructions with frequency 8% and CPI 2.
- Load instructions with frequency 20% and CPI 10.
- Store instructions with frequency 15% and CPI 4.
- Branches instructions with frequency 25% and CPI 3.

The average CPI is 3.83.

Since the average CPU is ∑F<sub>i</sub>·CPI<sub>i</sub>, with *F<sub>i</sub>* e *CPU<sub>i</sub>* being the parameters of the instruction type *i*, if the instruction type *j* change characteristics to *F<sub>k</sub>*, *CPI<sub>k</sub>* you can get the new average CPI with:

∑Fi<sub>i</sub>·CPI<sub>i</sub> - F<sub>j</sub>·CPI<sub>j</sub> + F<sub>k</sub>·CPI<sub>k</sub>

The first term is known, so this spares some calculation.
In this case: 4.15 - 0.8 + (0.32 * 1 + 0.08 * 2) = 3.83.

Choose whichever method is easier for you.

Comment: thank you! i surmised as much and attempted using the first method you outlined. But i definitely wanted the clarification. Thanks again!